# Implementing location search mongo +angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angularjs-directive

I have a site I am developing where I want users to be able to list gyms and then search them based on location. I do not know where to start but this is what I need.

1)Data Entry

*Auto-complete form for data accuracy.*
When users enter the gyms into the database I want to be able to have some feedback as they enter the data.

2)Data Retrieval

*Need a route for querying the parameters given.*

Ex: 
Gym in California
Gyms <  4Miles close to San-Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes-geo/

MongoDB does support geospatial queries, but all of that is based on longitude/latitude -- not in terms of street names.   So you will have to do some additional legwork

Comment: How can I have users enter their data and and then transfer that into LL AND Longitude.